# Do I have to complete another map to make progress on my Mann Up tour?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

So I'm doing the tour called "Operation Mecha Engine" and I have completed one map, and now my progress is 1/3. And so I was wondering do I have to complete the other 2 maps to make progress, or do I need to, or can I play and make progress on the same one I already completed?

Comment: You must complete the other maps in that same tour to get the loot for that tour. Redoing the same mission will not affect your progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete the tour, you need to complete all the missions in it. Completing the same mission repeatedly will not advance you further.

Comment: Completing the same mission will also not use one of your TOD tickets, if you're still on the same tour number.